# Git pushes all files even if nothing to commit

Tags: git, github

I have created a new GitHub project, which is empty (I still see the setup instructions in GitHub on my repository).
I have a server that contains a developement project, this is the folder and sub-folder that I want to have on GitHub. I ran `git init` on that folder.

When I push the master branch to the "origin" remote, even if I haven't added a file to the index (and when I run `git status`, it says "nothing to commit, working tree clean"), Git tries to push all the files of the project.

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean



Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12403/12403), done.
^Citing objects:  29% (3803/12687), 21.75 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s
```

I have tried to make a .gitignore file and completed him to avoid some sub folders to be sent, and tried to add and commit one unique file, that after that appears in the index by checking the status.

Could you explain why Git pushes all the files even if index is empty?

Comment: If there are some files, and `git status` says "nothing to commit, working tree clean", then you must have added these files to the repository at some point, therefore they are transferred to the remote repository when you push.

Comment: `Compressing objects: 100% (12403/12403), done.` this doesn't look like empty repository. Are you sure that you did `git init` in folder which is not already tracked by some repo? What `git init` printed?

Comment: At the time, git init says : Reinitialized existing Git repository in /srv/www/htdocs/version_en_dev/appli/.git/

Comment: To be honnest,I'm not 100% sure that the the folder is not already tracked.
Can i reset this if it's already tracked ?

Comment: "Reinitialized **existing** Git repository"... if you created a new repository it would have said "Initialized empty Git repository".

Comment: I have deleted the repository, created a new, deleted the old remote, created the new remote and the result is the same.

Comment: Looks like you are creating new repo in sub directory of existing one

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but I think this might help.

When executing `git push`, `git` pushes your local commits to the remote. It has nothing to do with if there's something in your staging area (tracked and untracked).

If you execute `git log`, you will see that you have local commits which are not in your remote. Those are the commits `git` is pushing to your remote when invoking the `git push` command.

The `git status` command just gives you a summary of files that are in your staging area. If the output is `nothing to commit, working tree clean`, that just means that all your files and changes have been commited locally. It does not tell you whether those commits have been pushed to your remote or not.

Comment: OK, then there is something I don't understand with git.
I thought that when you push, git send the files that are staged.
From what I read : "commit: adding changes to the local repository

push: to transfer the last commit(s) to a remote serve"

It says everywhere that push transfer the last commits to the remote server.

In other words : "git push is used to add commits you have done on the local repository to a remote one - together with git pull, it allows people to collaborate.".

Comment: @jska13 No, MFnx is right, push is not meant to send *staged files*, but *commits*. You only push commits in git.

Comment: OK so maybe I am mistaking staged and commits.
I thought that when you commit file(s), they are in the index (I thought that meant that they are staged, but ok staged is for tracked files).

Comment: @jska13 It is important to understand well the concepts of local files, staged files and remote files. git add adds files and/or changes to the staged area. git commit commits (locally) what's in the staged area (after commit, your staged area will be empty). git push pushes commits to the remote.

Comment: Yes, I try to understand all that.
Well problem is solved : i deleted .git folder, re-made all the process and it's good...I think I actually made a add . before at first try, waht caused all the files sync with the repo.